# VBA HTML drill down code [extracting <li> values in <ul> drop down list]

Tags: vba, web-scraping, html-lists, dropdown, unordered

I have been playing around with loading webpages into VBA as XML's and iterating through its data and have stumbled across a roadblock while trying to loop through the "li" tags nested in a "ul" tag. In theory it is very straightforward but why does this particular example not working? I have also searched every single forum for this answer without avail.

[image]

Basically the 'ul' class is called "*f-dropdown*" and it has sub 'li' with attributes called "*data-ti-html-select-option*". Im trying to get the innerHTML/innerText of the 'li' tag nested inside the 'ul'. Seems to be straightforward but when I create a for-loop for it which iterates through the HTML document flagging the 'ul' tag and looping the children within, it doesn't pick all the 'li' items inside.

Question here is how do I get to pull all 7 'li' tags inside the 'ul' tag? Based on the current code, it is pulling 3 out of 7 tags. It seems to only pull the first "**row collapse product size....**" class in the li attribute.

If it helps, this information is in a drop-down list and the pre-selected value is "pick a size". Welcome to any ideas/suggestions on how to scrape this kind of info.

```
Sub test_parse()

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim Products As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Product As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'website below is just dummy site
XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://www.testsite.com", False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

'setting <ul> tag as a element collection
Set Products = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("f-dropdown")

'looping through the <ul> collection and reading values
'Product --> children of the collection?
For Each Product In Products
    'Do i need to step down further and call another for-loop for Product.children?
    Debug.Print Product.innerHTML, Product.innerText
Next Product

'result of this code:
'<LI class="show-for-small-only takeover-header"><SPAN>Pick a size</SPAN> </LI>
'<LI class="row collapse disclaimer product-size-option" data-ng-show="!available &amp;&amp; available !== undefined">
'<DIV class="small-4 column text-center the-size">No Stock </DIV></LI>
'<LI class="row collapse product-size-option" data-ng-class="{'sold-out invalid': size.quantity === 0, 'selected': size.sku === product.simpleSku}" data-ti-html-select-option="size.sku" data-ng-repeat="size in sizes">
```

Comment: Have you investigated `getElementsByTagName("li")` which returns a collection of `li`'s?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that route of iterating though the whole html document for all ("li") tags and printing it in the worksheet hoping I could just pluck out the ones I want. But it's been weird as looping through the tagName gives out the same result and skips the subsequent row collapse product-size-option...

Comment: I have also tried using queryselector and it gave out the same result. I'm just stumped as to why it's omitting the rest of the "row collapse..." list items after reading the first one. Also it is a variable drop down box that changes from one product to the next eg. Current product might show sizes in 6, 7, 8, 9, next product might have sizes in S, M, L, XL with no consistency in sizing structure from one to the other. Is this a hidden/locked issue?

Comment: Are you doing `products.getElements...` ?

Comment: You'd want to do something like `set ListItems = product.getElementsByTagName("li")` inside the `For Each Product in Products` loop. This should yield each `li` inside the parent `ul` with a class of `f-dropdown`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried looping inside the for each product in products with the same output as before. I am wondering why I get the same results. It seems as though the other 'li' tags are hidden when I parse through the html document? Is that even possible, something like having to trigger events first to change the property of the item to visible?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - I have tried extracting all elements by tag name in product and came up with same result. Also tried looping one container higher than the f-dropdown class with the same result. Any more suggestions as to how this can be tweaked?

Comment: @RyanWildry - thanks for shooting that across, I was thinking the same too, it should be easy enough to extract the information but it isn't that straight forward. Stupid question time, are all the values presented in the html document in the inspect page available for extract/viewing in VBA or are there certain fields where it needs user-input eg. clicking, hovering, etc. to enable it and make the property visible?

Comment: @honeybadger It's possible they aren't rendered on page load, but an event instead. These elements might be generated dynamically based on some JS code on the page. In that case, I'm not sure using an XML request is the way to go. Might be easier to use browser automation.

Comment: @RyanWildry - Wow I cannot believe I haven't tried using the Internet Explorer method and it worked. Just for clarity, how is `Dim IE As New InternetExplorer` exactly different than `Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60`. Not all elements get loaded in the XML route compared to setting up the actual browser? I know it works already but just trying to explore different options as using Internet Explorer as the medium can slow things down significantly when scraping. Is there a different way within VBA to extract this information other than the XML request?

Comment: In general the browser will execute JavaScript, MSXML doesn't.

Comment: What's the actual url? Is it public?